# Text color when editing tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The tag editing page for posts seems pretty unreadable to me.  See screenshot below:

[image: Tag Editing Page]

Comment: The fix is on the way

Comment: Thanks @Jin, great job on the design BTW.  Very Apple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.